# Not able to delete the files from filesystem using java

Tags: java

I am performing some scenarios through java where i am downloading a file and storing it in a desired location.Then i am verifying it contents and trying to delete it. As i was trying to delete the file it was not happening as i got to know the file was open in Java(TM) Platform SE binary. And to resolve this issue i used "taskill" in my code given below. But the  program is getting terminated before it can perform the delete function("file.delete()"). Need help on this.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im javaw.exe");
    String filename=dataProvider.getPropertyvalue("Calculation","PDFFilePath");
    File file = new File(filename);
    file.delete();
```

Comment: Are you saying that after killing your java application, your java application doesn't do anything anymore ?

Comment: Did your program terminate because of an error ? If yes, what is this error ?

Comment: @Berger yes, if i don't kill the operation i won't be able to delete the file.

Comment: @Lutzi No, it is coming upto the below line and terminating without any error.
"Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im javaw.exe");"